# Cast from base generic type to derived generic type where the derived type has additional type constraints

Tags: c#, generics

Actually whilst casting would be the ideal even "newing up" the derived type would work in my specific scenario.  I suspect this isn't possible when I don't have access to the concrete type of the generic parameter.

```
public class OrderableCollection<T> : Collection<T> where T : IOrderable, new()
{
...
}

public class ArchivableOrderableCollection<T> : OrderableCollection<T> where T : IOrderable, IArchivable, new()
{
...
}

public class OrderableListDisplay<TItem> where TItem : IOrderable, new()
{
    protected OrderableCollection<TItem> orderableItems { get; set; }

    protected virtual async Task RestoreItem(TItem item)
    {
        if (item is not IArchivable)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        // None of these compile
        var aoc1 = orderableItems as ArchivableOrderableCollection<TItem>;
        var aoc2 = new ArchivableOrderableCollection<TItem>(orderableItems);
        var aoc3 = (ArchivableOrderableCollection<TItem>)(object)(OrderableItems);

        // I think I need something like
        var aoc4 = orderableItems as ArchivableOrderableCollection<TItem> where TItem : IArchivable
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a generic argument w/ constraints to your `RestoreItem` method

```
protected virtual async Task RestoreItem<T>(T item)
    where T : TItem, IArchivable
{
    if( orderableItems is not ArchivableOrderableCollection<T> items )
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    // do what you need to here
    items.Restore( item );
}
```

However, I think you should reconsider your design.  Implement base and derived classes for `OrderableListDisplay<T>` so that a derived version may constrain the `TItem` to `IArchivable` properly and expects and implementation of `ArchivableOrderableCollection<T>`:

```
public class OrderableListDisplay<TItem>
    where TItem : IOrderable, new()
{
    private readonly OrderableCollection<TItem> _items = null;

    public OrderableListDisplay( OrderableCollection<TItem> items )
    {
        _items = items ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( items ) );
    }
}

public class ArchivableOrderableListDisplay<TItem>
    : OrderableListDisplay<TItem>
    where TItem : IArchivable
{
    private readonly ArchivableOrderableCollection<TItem> _items = null;

    public ArchivableOrderableListDisplay( ArchivableOrderableCollection<TItem> items )
        : base( items )
    {
        _items = items;
    }

    protected async Task RestoreItem( TItem item )
    {
        _items.Restore( item );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I had the design you are suggested in the second part of you answer previously but what I don't say in the question is that ...ListDisplay classes are actually Blazor components and I didn't want to use inheritance (it isn't encouraged).  For the first part of you answer it seems to be missing the line that won't compile!  The var aoc1 = orderableItems as ArchivableOrderableCollection<TItem>;

Comment: the `if` statement takes care of that.  Please post link to where it says Blazor shouldn't use inheritance, I'd like to read it

Comment: ah yes.  Many thanks.

Comment: For the second part of your answer I'll also look for the links I read that made me give up on inheritance in Blazor components and I'll reconsider.

Comment: I was sure this compiled but actually: The type 'TItem' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'OrderableListDisplay<TItem>.RestoreItem<T>(T)'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TItem' to 'IntroducersBlazor.Shared.Interfaces.IArchivable'.

Comment: Not sure what you're doing but here's a fiddle demonstration: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bdbe4B

Comment: OK I think the issue is actually that the RestoreItem method is being called from inside OrderableListDisplay, it's being called from a Blazor button onclick handler so I can't (or don't know how to) specify the generic parameters in the @onclick="" tag.  It is analogous to the RestoreFirstItem method in this fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/eFuaCA - I can add constraints to RestoreFirstItem but then I'm back to how to put these in the onclick handler.  This is obviously a different question to the original one which you have answered.

Comment: I should say this is academic interest only at this point, I have worked around the issue, but I am interested to see if it is possible.